# spring mvc + spring security + angularjs rounting integration

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, integration

In my project, i'm using Spring MVC 4.1.6 for REST service + Spring Security 3.2.5 for Authentication and access control + AngularJS for one-page application style front-end. Having a problem with the routing integration.

I have a problem with the login page routing, which is made as the AngularJS ng-view element of the main static page (so it loads dynamically)
=> conciquently, it has it's **route in AngularJS**

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/view/Main.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    }).
    when('/user-login', {
        templateUrl : '/view/user/user-login.jsp',
        controller : 'user-loginController'
    });
```

It is also defined as a login URL in **Spring Security config**

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- enable use-expressions -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <headers>
        <cache-control />
    </headers>

    <intercept-url pattern="/api/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/api/items**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403"/>

    <form-login
            login-processing-url="/login/processing"
            login-page="/user-login"
            default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/user-login"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="failureHandler"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/api/user-login?logout"  delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    <!-- enable csrf protection -->
    <csrf/>
</http>
```

So, the **problem is:**
The login page works ok. But, when the reuqest is handled by Spring security config (for example

```
  <intercept-url pattern="/user**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
```

)

and the user doesn't have this role, it is redirected to the login page '/user-login'.  But, in this case, some routing conflict occurs and i'm getting 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.' error in browser, and it continiously keeps redirecting me to '/user-login' page like 20-30 times.

Any idea, how to solve this conflict? I tried to make just null Spring controller for 'user-login' but it doesn't helps

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user-login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayLoginPage() {
    return null;
}
```

The only idea i have, is to separate login page from the one-page app to not use the angular routing for it, but that isn't a good option.

Comment: Please post entire spring security configuration. Perhaps you are missing this: <intercept-url pattern="/user-login" requires-channel="https" access="permitAll"/>

Comment: updated (excluding beans).

Comment: when i tried to add the patter u suggested - getting this error when '/user-login' loaded by spring security 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'.
if it's loaded by angular routing - nothing, just working.